# how can i access on arrays in ironpython?

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

Sorry for my bad English..
I'm programming in Ironpython a WPF Apllication.
I want to storage the number, which is in self.nummer.Text, in the variable a[1].
how can i do this?
this don't work(list):

```
def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        self.mitarbeiter.Content=1
        array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    def eingabe(self, sender, e):
        for x in range(1,13):
                a = self.nummer.Text
                self.tt.Content = a
```

and this also don't work (arrays):

```
import wpf
from Window1 import *
from System import Array
from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
        self.mitarbeiter.Content=1
        array = Array[int]((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
    def eingabe(self, sender, e):
        for x in range(1,13):
                array[x] = self.nummer.Text
                self.tt.Content = array[x]
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In python you usually use list instead of array [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

```
test = []
test.append("Hello")
test.append("Hello second time")

print(test)
test.insert(0, "Hello first time")
print(test)
```

You could, just use the *test.insert(0,* value) to get the desired effect.

Instead of doing this:

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Do this:

```
a = [0] * 12
```

My guees is that you need to change you code to the below. In your code you create the array, but then in the function you try to store the value to another variable that you declare in a loop. That is not possible to do, either you do as I have below, or you initiate the array before entering the loop.

```
def __init__(self):
    wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
    self.mitarbeiter.Content=1
    array_a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

def eingabe(self, sender, e):
    for x in range(1,13):
            self.array_a.insert(x, self.nummer.Text)
            self.tt.Content = a
```

Comment: but how can i storage a number in a list?

Comment: If you want to add number 7 to index 0, you write:
test.insert(0, 7).

Then the number is stored in the list. You can verify it with: 
print(test)

Comment: String and int works the same way when inserting into an list. When you do this: a = [0] * 12 you actually store 12 zeros in the list

Comment: so do you mean this?  x is the part where in the list i want to isert it, and sef.nummer.text is the textbox
   
                a.insert(x,self.nummer.Text)